# PHP Guru about script timeouts

Tags: php, timeout

Sometimes I get random PHP execution timeouts.  Is there a way to troubleshoot where it is coming from?  A way to debug this?

Thanks...

Comment: You are running php under a werbserver or in shell? You have many ways... Try see (tail -f) syslog, messages and configure php erros into a specific file

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure which part of the code is taking a lot of time, you can grab time stamps before and after each portion of code, compare then for the difference in time, and report those out.  This will let you know which pieces of your code take the longest.

If you have random timeouts, and the script usually processes very quickly, then I would guess it's one of two things (I'm sure there are MANY more scenarios than this):

1) If you're connecting to an external source that isn't responding, that could cause a timeout
2) You have a dynamic piece of code that can process very little or a lot of information depending on the environment and user (for instance, you allow image uploads, or dynamic sql queries, etc)

If you have code (even pseudo code) that could describe the situation, it could make it easier for us to see where there may be problems.

Comment: I don't have any actual code however it is happening in the backend of wordpress.  When doing a update/save function of a plugin, it sometimes give me timeout...